# Eclipse (Java) freezes up my whole computer when I run a program

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know why I have this problem, and out of nowhere, it happened. Everytime I run any program on Eclipse, it literally freezes everything on my computer, including my cursor. Sometimes I would resolve this problem by force shutting my computer, or force-closing Eclipse. I did nothing but change some code to cause this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Smells of a broken RAM module, but it's hard to tell with so little info.

Comment: maybe creating a endless loop? Since changing some code caused the problem

Comment: try increasing max heap value Xmx in eclipse.ini

Comment: This might caused by a plugin you have installed. Make also sure, that your Eclipse is up-to-date (the current Eclipse version is 2020-06).

Comment: I never had an endless loop. This happened when I ran my gui which didn't show up, and also when I changed tabs. The only plug-in I have is the window builder.

Comment: Does your computer also freeze when you run your program outside of Eclipse as a standalone version? That would mean it's not an Eclipse problem.

Comment: In the run configuration, you can use the _Show Command Line_ button to get the command line command to test what @ModusTollens says (on Windows the Windows Defender or other anti-virus might cause this).

Comment: I couldn't find the show command line button on the run configuration, idk why. Also to add, none of my programs would run or show anything even after compiling.

Comment: Update: just updated eclipse and increased heap size to 2048. Problem still remains. I think I'm going to call the company.